# Second monitor always black Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm, trying to connect the second monitor with my Mac Book Retina. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it, and it detect the second display, but the screen is alway black...

I connected it with a hdmi cable and I'm using the nvdia driver.
[image]

What can I do?

**EDIT**

If I use the display port - VGA adapter it works.. I have no idea how solve it

**EDIT**

As you can see here, the HDMI display is detected and if I ashow all desktop, I see 8 different deskopt (when you press cmd+S or windows+S)
[image]

Comment: How is the monitor usually connected (when not using the adapter), what port? What monitor?

Comment: I suppose it's HDMI... Weird, a direct HDMI connection not working where a VGA adapter does. Is it a HDMI->VGA adapter that then connects to the VGA input in the monitor? If so, the problem might be in the monitor.

Comment: At some point you perhaps should edit and update your question with a few more details about your setup and settings. Your MacBook has a miniDP port only. HDMI is also an adapter (which may be defective). But it also can be due to the resolution and multi-monitor settings. Please update the question with such settings and the MacBook's and Asus monitor's native resolutions.